# linq query to return nested list for unique items

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a linq query as:

```
            var leaveDetails = (from l in leaveList
            group l by new {l.LeaveDateStart.Year, l.LeaveType}
            into yearGroup
            select new 
            {
                yearGroup.Key.Year,
                yearGroup.Key.LeaveType,
                LeaveTaken = yearGroup.Sum(l => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(l.LeaveDateStart, l.LeaveDateEnd))

            }).ToList();
```

With the results shown below:

[image: Image showing query results]
However I want to group by distinct year. So that for each unique year I have a list of leave types and the leave days taken.

I have tried doing it in the front-end in javascript but it looks messy. Is there a way I can do it in C# or the linq query. Thanks

Comment: just not grouping by `l.LeaveType`, and you get list with unique year

Comment: Group by result that you have by year, and you're done.

Comment: @Maarten sounds workable. You mind posting as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a current result which is grouped by year and leave-type. You can simply group your current result by year, and select the leave-type and leave-taken as value-per-group.

Like this (note: haven't tested it):

```
var leaveDetailsPerYear = (from l in leaveDetails
                           group l by l.Year
                           into yearGroup
                           select new {
                                Year = yearGroup.Key,
                                Data = yearGroup.ToList()
                           }
                          )
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks this worked fine with a minor edit. 'Year = yearGroup.Key' in the select statement.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Corrected.